# Bootstrap JS Modal and Menu Toggle Dispute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

TL;DR Changing the order (or removing) the Bootstrap JS affects which module works properly.

I have been looking high and low for an answer to this specific question, but nothing has quite remedied the situation..here goes.

On my page, I have the 'hamburger' dropdown menu on the left-hand side and a sign up button (to call a modal) on the right hand side using Bootstrap. Here's the JS order I call at the bottom of my footer.php:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

By changing the order of the JS, I can get one of the two modules working. Lemme explain:

Situation #1 (using the order above): I click the mobile 'hamburger' menu and the menudrops down BUT when clicked again, it refuses to go back up (you can see it move slightly but it still stays down). I read that this is a multiple jQuery/js issue. So I went ahead and checked my header and footer.php and no other bootstrap javascripts were being called. HOWEVER, when I delete the `bootstrap.min.js`the menu toggle works like a charm. Note: The modal popup works perfectly as well.

Situation #2: By moving the `bootstrap.min.js`to the top of the scripts, the menu works as expected, BUT now the signup button, when clicked, will display the modal briefly and then disappear. These issues can be resolved by removing the `bootstrap.min.js` again....

So my question is, is the bootstrap.js being called by any one of these other scripts? B/c the problem ceases to exist once that file is removed!

Thanks everyone for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching the order of your last two script files to this. Seems like bootstrap is overriding your custom script file because it is declared below it. once your remove bootstrap it seems to work like a charm

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

Secondly, you are using bootstrap-css for their classes but you are using main.js for toggling menu.

so both of the script are colliding with each other
either you should change your class that you're calling in main.js or you should use bootstrap.js entirely
like in bootstrap it calls the button with class="navbar-toggle" to toggle the menu
if you are using somethig like $(".navbar-toggle") in your main.js then they would interfere with each other.

For you modal problem: Since it is working for short time, it may be the case tha the modal-toggle is being called by two scripts simultaneously.

Find the modal portion in bootstrap.js and comment it out.

Comment: unfortunately this didnt work. Bootstrap menu still will not toggle back up once down. This worked flawlessly in my static HTML setup so I dont know why this issue is now showing up. What information can I provide to help solve this?

Comment: is your website online?

Comment: if not then upload a zip of your files on zippyshare . I'll to take a look at it

Comment: awesome thank you. It's still in development so just working in Localhost. Here's a zippyshare that contains the custom theme (I've only added content to header, footer and page-home.php): http://www50.zippyshare.com/v/gVplvH5E/file.html

Comment: Also, Let me know if you need any more info, I would be happy to provide

Comment: sorry, I tried to recreate your page on my localhost but seems like you are using wordpress function, so it failed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131004/discussion-between-jordan-lewallen-and-anuja-agarwal).

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue when all my menu changed colour when I started using a new jquery / bootstrap modal. To sort this issue I have change the order and put all together at menu.php page.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



<!--Bootstrap Menu Stuff-->  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


<!--Bootstrap Modal Stuff-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```